# regex to allow only alphabets and no special characters, with no space at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried this: but this isn't working as expected. However it restricts user to enter space at the beginning. where did I made the mistake?

Regex that I have tried to build so far: `[^-\s][a-zA-Z\s]*$`

Should Match: priya, Abc Xyz 
Should not match: `<spaces>binayak`, $&&ay%%aac

Comment: I think you missed a link in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you missed the beginning of string anchor `^`.

Secondly, the inverse character class `[^-\s]` is a good attempt at not allowing spaces, but at the same time it does allow other special characters to be at the beginning of the string, which we do not want. Instead, we could just something very similar to the second character class, just without the `\s`: `[a-zA-Z]`.

Full regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Comment: That's not quite right. According to [regex 101](https://regex101.com/), `binayak` with a space in front matches. I'd advise first using an `indexOf(' ') != 0` check before the regex.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper It worked for me buddy. And thanks for the brief explanation.